# Replacing string in file with MAC OSX

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, macos

I need to replace a string in a (large) file on a MacOSX 10.10. My file looks like this:

```
Y16-TUL-SUB_ Y16-TUL-SUB_ Y16-TUL-SUB_ Y16-TUL-SUB_ Y16-TUL-SUB-
Y16-TUL-SUB_ Y16-TUL-SUB_
```

and I need to replace `Y16_TUL_SUB_` with `Y16-TUL-SUB-`. File name could be `test.txt`.

I have tried a lot of the different suggestions with `sed`, `awk` and `python`. E.g this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python import sys import os import tempfile

 tmp=tempfile.mkstemp()

 with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd1, open(tmp[1],'w') as fd2:
     for line in fd1:
         line = line.replace('Y16_TUL_SUB_','Y16-TUL-SUB-')
         fd2.write(line)

 os.rename(tmp[1],sys.argv[1])
```

or `sed` supposedly for mac

or `find`:

```
 find . -type f -name test.txt | xargs sed -i ""
 "s/Y16_TUL_SUB_/Y16-TUL-SUB-/g'
```

or `sed`:

```
 sed -i -e "s/Y16_TUL_SUB_/Y16-TUL-SUB/g" test.txt
```

or `awk`

```
 awk '{gsub(/Y16_TUL_SUB_/,"Y16-TUL-SUB")}' test.txt
```

All these commands have run and returned empty output files, or not changed anything in the original files anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 18):

How it to do with `sed` in OS X.

I've created test file:

```
$ cat test.txt
tasdasdasd

asd
asd
as
d
as
d
ddddddd

ffdfdfdfdfdf
```

Calling `sed` (`''` is necessarily parameter):

```
$ sed -i '' "s/as/replaced_ad/g" test.txt
```

Show output file:

```
$ cat test.txt
treplaced_addreplaced_addreplaced_add

replaced_add
replaced_add
replaced_ad
d
replaced_ad
d
ddddddd

ffdfdfdfdfdf
```

`sed` in OS X is slightly changes from GNU `sed`. Use `man sed` in OS X terminal to know how to use `sed`.

Comment: Hi Yurij, I appreciate your help, but unfortunately this does nothing for me. Once again, no changes in file. :( Output file is empty

Comment: When I copy-paste (or write myself) your EXACT command on the EXACT file you display, the output file I get is empty.

Comment: This exact command worked for me on Catalina. But I have ohmyzsh, maybe it changes standard sed

Comment: "sed in OS X is slightly change[d] from GNU sed." - Of course it is. Apple has to pollute everything!

Answer (score 4):

Weird. Replacing " with ' apparently worked.

```
sed -i '' "s/as/replaced_ad/g" test.txt
```

did nothing, whereas

```
sed -i '' 's/as/replaced_ad/g' test.txt
```

gave me what I needed. ?????

I thought there were no difference between single and double quotes on machos?????

Well, as long as I can go on with my work..... Thanks Yurij, again.